# Data bind multiple controls to same clr property results in strange behavior in the control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

**Requirement**

My requirement is to display the textbox value in a different read only control like label or textblock on the same window.

**Solution Approach**

TextBox's and TextBlock's target property Text are data bound to the same source object (a simple CLR Property of type string). The bounded source property implements property change notification via INotifyPropertyChanged.

**Observations**

At runtime the textBox become readonly and user is unable to manually change the text of the textbox.
Question: How is textbox's editablity getting affected by the presence of a text block . I understand that the TextBox default binding mode is two way while that of textblock is one way. But I am unable to understand the reason behind this. Also, how should I solve this problem.

**XAML**

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtBox" Text="{Binding Name }"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private string _name = "Welcome";
public string Name
{
    get
    { return _name; }
    set
    {
        if(_name!= value)
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

The TextBox is still readonly even if I set the data bound the Text property of the TextBlock to the text property of TextBox. Even if I use a label control instead a textblock I get the same behavior.

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtBox" Text="{Binding Name }"/>
 <TextBlock Height="20" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtBox, Path=Text}"/>
```

Please help me with the reasoning behind this behavior.

Comment: well... this seems unlikely. are you sure your textbox does not have some implicit style for example... where isreadonly property is set to true? I can't reproduce this behavior.

Comment: First of all check what ViktorLaCroix wrote, because that seems the most likely problem. You might also want to search for OverrideMetadata calls to check if somewhere someone messes with properties of TextBoxes in general. And the reason behind the binding modes is rather simple: TextBoxes are input and output controls, so it is assumed that in most cases you want to retrieve data but also want to write data back, therefore it defaults to TwoWay. The TextBlock on the other hand has no way of modifying the data, therefore its OneWay, so it can only read the data.

Comment: No there are no styles defined on the textbox. When I tried in a fresh sample application it works. But it does not work in my existing wpf project. The difference is that in my existing project I am using Prism and MVVM light Toolkit. The ViewModel extends the ViewModelBase class provided by MVVMLight Toolkit. I am still wondering why is this strange behavior. It works in an isolated application however fails in existing project. Anyways, thanks a lot for spending time on this. I only have to dig deeper to figure out which module is overriding the textbox behavior in my existing application.

Comment: so have you checked if as soon as you comment the `TextBlock` and re-run your app, the `TextBox` is no longer read-only? and this behavior only occurs when the `TextBlock` is there as well, cos if it occurs even without the `TextBlock` it's almost sure it's as @ViktorLaCroix mentioned and you can go into tracing that.

Comment: yes if I databound the textblock to some other property it works